# use of "this" in react class component function vs arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When using `this` on react class component like this:

```
someFunc() {
  console.log(this.props.someProp);
}
```

I get `undefined`.

But when I use `this` inside a lifecycle method of react like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props.someProp);
}
```

I get the value of `someProp`.

I'm searching for an explanation for this behavior, can someone help?

Comment: Are you using someFunc as a _callback_? Give a [mre]. And what do you mean "vs arrow function" - what arrow function?

Comment: you have to bind the `this` in the function you define yourself. eg in your costructor you have to type `this.someFunc = this.someFunc.bind(this)`

Comment: You'll need to show us how you use (call) `someFunc`, and how you want to use an arrow function instead